# Travis CI build cordova android application

Tags: cordova, travis-ci

Is it possible to using Travis CI instead of PhoneGap build to build application and let someone else to download the APK?

I'm using the following yml [file](https://gist.github.com/qertis/acd71e14db4168832f3b67c75182af04).